# Creating 3D Grid From Vectors

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to create a 3DGrid from 3D Vectors. I have never done this before so I'm not sure what to do.

I first thought to create just the boundaries so I have a cube. Now I need to add points to my cube. How exactly do I create points using vectors? I'm not even sure what methods I should include.

Can someone help me step by step in the thought process of creating this?

Comment: Have you tried reading a tutorial or book on 3D graphics? Are you using a 3D framework or do you want to write the 3D routines from scratch?

Comment: I have to write everything from scratch for my course. The assignment is to just create a Grid3d<T> from Vector 3D. (Class we already created)

Comment: Well, a vector may hold 2 or more components of a direction, i.e X,Y for 2d or X,Y,Z for 3d. You may interpret them as a direction with a magnitude, _or_ you may interpret them as an absolute position. It's really just up to you. It seems quite likely to me (from almost zero information) that you could simply think of these vectors as points in 3d space.

Comment: Agree with enhzflep.  Assuming you want to go from points to grid(mesh), Then the vectors can be used as the points(just interpret them as x,y,z coordinates), or the direction you used to pass your line segment through to connect the points in your grid.